# Font Panel to change Text Field Font

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts, interface-builder

I Setup a Push Button to open up a Font Panel like they did shown in this question:
[Make NSButton open fonts panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917738/make-nsbutton-open-fonts-panel)

I did all of these through the Interface Builder by dragging buttons and Labels onto the MainMenu View and i have nothing inside my AppDelegate.h and .m

Im really new to objective c and cocoa so i was wondering if anyone could give me an in depth explanation on how to use that font panel to edit the font in a Label or a Text Field.

Comment: You can't use those on iOS.

Comment: What do you mean by that? can u give a more detailed answer? Or suggest another way i can edit font of label/text field with a GUI

Comment: You tagged iOS. MainMenu and panel are for OS X only. For iOS, you should use UIButton, UIFont and the like.

Comment: sorry i meant osx >_< how would you do this for OS X then?