# How to change Label Font with the FontsPanel in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I made a PushButton to open up a Font Panel like they did here:[Make NSButton open fonts panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917738/make-nsbutton-open-fonts-panel)

I did all of these through the Interface-Builder by dragging buttons and Labels onto the MainMenu View and i have nothing inside my AppDelegate.h and .m

Im really new to objective c and cocoa so i was wondering if anyone could give me an in depth explanation on how to use that font panel to edit the font in a Label or a Text Field.

Answer (score 0):

Both label and text field are class NSTextField. 
The style of the text they display is determined by the attributes on their NSAttributedString. 
The Attributed String Programming Guide on Apple's developer site goes into detail on how to handle attributes. The font is one of those inside an attribute called paragraph style.

That should get you started on what to look into.

The Cocoa text architecture is pretty rich and can take some time to get familiar with.

One thing to note, when a text field is in edit mode, it uses something called the field editor for rendering , which is normally a shared instance of NSTextView that is owned by the window and basically appears in front of the text field during editing.

Comment: How would i retrieve the info data the Fonts Panel tho and modify the NSAttributedString though?